# Create features from ArcGIS Topology errors

Tags: arcgis-desktop, topology

I have imported field users shapefiles into an ESRI geodatabase so that I can create some topology rulesets that identifies the errors as needed.  Unfortunately the field users do not have a license that can read gdb topology rules (or obviously fix them).

I would like to be able to generate a new set of shapefiles that capture where all of the errors and exceptions are at so the users can go in an fix the obvious ones themselves (saving me a bunch of work!).  This can also be a quick way of organizing the errors based on size (area or length) so that you deal with the biggest issues first.

Does anyone have any suggestions on a way to generate features from ArcGIS Topology errors & exceptions?

I have an ArcInfo license available so any tool within the package is at my disposal.  While I am not an ArcObjects programmer, I am very familiar with Python scripts or ModelBuilder to develop such a tool/process.

**UPDATE**: I did just find this [ArcGIS Idea](http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=0873000000087yrAAA) and [developer sample](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/CPP_VB6_VBA_VCPP_Doc/COM_Samples_Docs/Geodatabase/Creating_and_Converting_Data/Export_Topology_Errors/5308b3e6-4a0a-4236-97e3-22d1f28b12af.htm), but I was hoping for something that I would be able to put into a toolbox, not a custom VB module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ArcGIS 10.1 for Desktop has a new geoprocessing tool called [Export Topology Errors](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000015w000000) (the tool is mentioned in that ArcGIS Ideas link).

> Exports the errors from a geodatabase topology to the target
>   geodatabase. All information associated with the errors and
>   exceptions, such as the features referenced by the error or exception,
>   are exported. Once they are exported, the feature classes can be
>   accessed using any license level of ArcGIS. The feature classes can be
>   used with the Select by Location dialog box or the Select Layer By
>   Location tool and can be shared with other users who do not have
>   access to the topology itself.

Comment: True, it doesn't help me today, but glad it will be readily available in the future.  Thanks for posting.

Comment: Here's a blog entry from ESRI regarding the [Export Topology Errors tool](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2013/02/07/export-topology-errors/).

Answer (score 4):

For ArcGIS 9x

**Export Topology Exceptions**

*This code will export Topology Error Exceptions to a feature class. This is useful when one needs to archive Exceptions. When the exceptions are exported to the feature class they can be treated just like any other feature (attribute update/notes, identify). 
**Then Export to Shapefile for your other users.***

Tip:Create a Button and call InitiateExport from the Click Event

http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=12758

Answer (score 1):

Hope you will get the solution by downloading a version1.zip file from the below given link..
http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/6188-Export-topology-errors-tool